# Listview item text is not showing

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I am trying to implement the listview object in my application but, for some reason my listview is not showing text on any of the items. The items are added, and showing the small icon.

The result I would like (screenshot www).

[image: Listview example]

My current result

[image: My result]

Below is the code that I use to generate the listview. The listview is added on the winform using the designer.

```
Public Class OccurrenceControl

    ' Local variable
    Private _occurrence As Inventor.ComponentOccurrence

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ' Create a new image list
        Dim imageList As ImageList = New ImageList()
        imageList.ImageSize = New Drawing.Size(32, 32)

        imageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.MateConstraint)
        imageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.AngleConstraint)
        imageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.TangentConstraint)
        imageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.InsertConstraint)

        ' Set the listview small images list
        lvConstraints.SmallImageList = imageList

        ' Make the list scrollable
        lvConstraints.Scrollable = True

        ' Set the listview view type
        lvConstraints.View = View.List

    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowInfo(ByVal Occurrence As Inventor.ComponentOccurrence)
        ' Populate the local variable with the passed occurrence
        _occurrence = Occurrence

        ' Clear all listed constraints
        lvConstraints.Items.Clear()

        ' Set the grounded checkbox value
        cbGrounded.Checked = Occurrence.Grounded

        ' Loop all constraints.
        For Each oConstraint As Inventor.AssemblyConstraint In Occurrence.Constraints

            ' Create a new listview item
            Dim oListItem As New ListViewItem

            ' Give the listview item a name
            oListItem.Name = oConstraint.Name

            ' Add a image based on the constraint type.
            If oConstraint.Type = Inventor.ObjectTypeEnum.kFlushConstraintObject Or Inventor.ObjectTypeEnum.kMateConstraintObject Then
                oListItem.ImageIndex = 0
            ElseIf oConstraint.Type = Inventor.ObjectTypeEnum.kAngleConstraintObject Then
                oListItem.ImageIndex = 1
            ElseIf oConstraint.Type = Inventor.ObjectTypeEnum.kTangentConstraintObject Then
                oListItem.ImageIndex = 2
            ElseIf oConstraint.Type = Inventor.ObjectTypeEnum.kInsertConstraintObject Then
                oListItem.ImageIndex = 3
            End If

            ' Add the new listview item to the listview
            lvConstraints.Items.Add(oListItem)

        Next

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the `Text` of the `ListViewItem` anywhere so it's no surprise that no text is being displayed.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but now the text is only showning the first letter A.. instead of Angle hmmpf

Comment: If something didn't work, my first guess has to be that you did it wrong.  Edit your question and show us what you did and then we can see if there is something wrong with it.